LazyColumn and error @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
I have a Composable that shows for each category a line with a dropdown etc and when i try to do a Foreach category do a line in the app so people can click and select a level it shows the Composable error @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
levels Contains the List Of Categories
    LazyColumn(
                 modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                 verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
              ) {
                 levels?.forEach { category ->
                     CategoryItem(category) //Error happens here
                }
            }
*emphasized text*

This is what CategoryItem Does:
@Composable
    fun CategoryItem(category: Category) {
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {
            ClickableSquare(
                onClick = { expanded =!expanded },
                text = category.name
            )

            if (expanded) {
                DropdownMenu(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
                ) {
                    category.levels.forEach { level ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            text = { Text(text = level.name) },
                            onClick = {
                                // Navigate to GameScreen with level data
                                navController.navigate(route = AppScreens.GameScreen.route + "/${level.code}")
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


With LazyColumn, you can't use an ordinary loop to emit UI elements. Instead, you need to use the LazyListScope DSL like the item() and items() functions. Here's an example:
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
) {
    items(levels) {
        CategoryItem(it)
    }
}

Additionally, it's important to use the key parameter within the items() function, especially when your list items can be reordered.
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
) {
    items(
        items = levels,
        key = { it.id }
    ) { level ->
        CategoryItem(level)
    }
}


here it says that Cannot find a parameter with this name: items in "items = levels" im Missing something?

While typing, make sure you select the items(List<T> items, ...) function from the context assist. Also check that you have imported import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items.
